# Count combination of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say we have the following df:

| **id** | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 786 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The `id` column represents a unique client.

Columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` represent a product. These columns' values are binary.

`1` means the client has that product.
`0` means the client doesn't have that product.

I want to create a matrix table of sorts that counts the number of combinations of products that exist for all users.

This would be the desired output, given the df provided above:

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Your output seems incorrect, and should be symmetrical

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('table.dat', infer_nrows=1001)
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df2 = df[cols]
df2.T.dot(df2)
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   2   1   0   0
B   1   2   1   0
C   0   1   1   0
D   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product:

```
df2 = df.set_index('id')

out = df2.T.dot(df2)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  2  1  0  0
B  1  2  1  0
C  0  1  1  0
D  0  0  0  0
```